# Python Dictionary - Consolidating Leaf Nodes below a threshold

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, decision-tree, pruning

Below is a simplified example of a decision tree (`dict()`) that I trained in Python:

```
tree= {'Age': {'> 55': 0.4, '< 18': {'Income': {'high': 0, 'low': 0.2}}, 
               '18-35': 0.25, '36-55': {'Marital_Status': {'single': {'Income': 
               {'high': 0, 'low': 0.1}}, 'married': 0.05}}}}
```

The numbers in the leaf nodes (boxes) represent the probability of a class label (e.g. TRUE) appearing in that node. Visually, the tree looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to code a **generic** post-pruning algorithm that consolidates the nodes that have values less than `0.3` to their parent nodes. So the resulting tree with a `0.3` threshold would look like this when plotted:

[image]

In the second figure, please note that the `Income` node at `Age<18` has now been consolidated unto the root node `Age`. And the  `Age=36-55, Marital_Staus` has been consolidated to `Age` since the sum of all its leaf nodes (at multiple levels) is less then 0.3.

This is the incomplete pseudo-code I came up with (so far):

```
def post_prune  (dictionary, threshold):

    for k in dictionary.keys():

        if isinstance(dictionary[k], dict): # interim node

            post_prune(dictionary[k], threshold)

        else: # leaf node

            if dictionary[k]> threshold:
                pass
            else:
                to_do = 'delete this node'
```

Wanted to post the question since I feel this should have been solved numerous times.

Thank you.

P.S: I am not going to use the end result for classification, so pruning this way (cosmetically) works.

Comment: `self.post_prune(dictionary[k], threshold)` Is this a method of a class? Then you should add the `self` parameter to the method's signature.

Comment: yes it is, but I simplified it for here. I changed it so it is consistent now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
def simplify(tree, threshold):
    # simplify tree bottom-up
    for key, child in tree.items():
        if isinstance(child, dict):
            tree[key] = simplify(child, threshold)
    # all child-nodes are leafs and smaller than threshold -> return max
    if all(isinstance(child, str) and float(child) <= threshold 
           for child in tree.values()):
        return max(tree.values(), key=float)
    # else return tree itself
    return tree
```

Example:

```
>>> tree= {'Age': {'> 55': '0.4', '18-35': '0', \
                   '< 18': {'Income': {'high': '0', 'low': '0.2'}}, \
                   '36-55': {'Marital_Status': {'single': {'Income': {'high': '0', 'low': '0.1'}}, \
                                                'married': '0.3'}}}}
>>> simplify(tree, 0.2)
{'Age': {'> 55': '0.4', '< 18': '0.2', '18-35': '0', 
         '36-55': {'Marital_Status': {'single': '0.1', 'married': '0.3'}}}}
```

---

*Update:* Seems like I misunderstood your question: You want the simplified tree to hold the *sums* of the leafs if *their sum* is smaller than the threshold! Your suggested edit was slightly off. Try this:

```
def simplify(tree, threshold):
    # simplify tree bottom-up
    for key, child in tree.items():
        if isinstance(child, dict):
            tree[key] = simplify(child, threshold)
    # all child-nodes are leafs and sum smaller than threshold -> return sum
    if all(isinstance(child, str) for child in tree.values()) \
           and sum(map(float, tree.values())) <= threshold:
        return str(sum(map(float, tree.values())))
    # else return tree itself
    return tree
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I made a small change to the leaf node condition to make it more generic. I coded something similar to this but the problem is: let's say a first pass consolidation of  `'< 18': {'Income': {'high': '0', 'low': '0.2'}}` to `'< 18': '0.2'` may open up more opportunities to consolidate at a higher level. Is this code generic enough or does it only run a single pass?

Comment: Yes, due to the bottom-up recursion, it will first simplify the lower levels before trying to simplify the higher ones. Try for yourself: Just pass a higher threshold, like `0.3` or `1.0`.